# Swift: Segue Error when calling

Tags: swift, segue, viewcontroller

I have a segue setup in my swift class called ViewController and I am calling from a tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath. I am using this code in my segue

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {

        var svc = segue!.destinationViewController as Homework;

       svc.subject = subject_name

}
```

To tell it to set a varible called subject which is declared like this `var subject:NSString!` to a varible called subject_name. I then call it from my tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath using this code  `prepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue(), sender: AnyObject?())`.

This is my didSelectRowAtIndex

```
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();
        var currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        println(currentCell.textLabel!.text)
        subject_name = currentCell.textLabel.text
//        // Showing new storyboard
        performSegueWithIdentifier("Homework", sender: self)
        let vc : AnyObject! = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Homework")
        self.showViewController(vc as UIViewController, sender: vc)
    }
```

But when I go and run the app, and click the table view cell I get this error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value", and a green arrow points towards `var svc = segue!.destinationViewController as Homework;`. I tested the exact same code out on another app expect with the segue being called when a button is clicked and that worked perfectly, I also tried answers from [Calling segue programatically not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777465/calling-segue-programatically-not-working), and [Preparing for segue in embedded tableView in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26113910/preparing-for-segue-in-embedded-tableview-in-swift). Both of these answers did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you are calling `prepareForSegue()`. You shouldn't, that is automatically invoked.

What you should do instead is calling `performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?)`. That triggers a segue invocation, which automatically executes `prepareForSegue()`.

The `identifier` parameter is the one you set from IB: select the segue and look at the attributes inspector.

Besides that, @AnthonyKong's answer is a safer way to deal with optionals (a segue in this case) - that ensures that no runtime exception is thrown.

**Addendum**
Looking at your updated question, specifically at the implementation of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. The last 2 lines:

```
let vc : AnyObject! = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Homework")
self.showViewController(vc as UIViewController, sender: vc)
```

are redundant - if you perform a segue, that will instantiate the destination view controller, so you don't have to do it manually. Remove those lines.

Comment: @Antinio Sorry I don't understand you want I am supposed to put in for the indentifier

Comment: Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.sundoginteractive.com/sunblog/posts/performing-segues-in-ios-programmatically) - it's for objc, but same concept

Comment: @Antinio I took at look at that tutorial and but in if (segue.identifier == "Homework") {} to my code and added performSegueWithIdentifier("Homework", sender: self) but I get the error terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: did you add the `performSegueWithIdentifier` in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: Yes i replaced it with my old code in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: Which line is causing the exception?

Comment: The green arrow is pointing at class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

Comment: Hard to figure out without looking at the code. Can you post the relevant section of your code? at least `prepareForSegue` (if anything is missing from what currently in your question) and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: The performSegueWithIdentifier is still giving me the same error, do you know whats wrong

Comment: From what I've seen so far, I can't find anything wrong in your code, so I have no idea. Maybe unless the destination view controller is in another storyboard, or if you haven't associated in IB the dest view controller to the corresponding class (custom class from identity inspector)

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean I know it is the performSegueWithIdentifier code as I deleted everything in the segue and it still crashes, but I don't get what you mean about the dest view controller to the corresponding class could you please explain

Comment: there's too much to say, and it looks like you're missing some basics about xcode and IB. I highly recommend reading/watching tutorials, there are many on raywenderlich.com, appcoda.com, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this instead:

```
if let svc = segue!.destinationViewController as? Homework {
       svc.subject = subject_name
}
```

It is because you might get passed other segues which do not have Homework as desination VC

Comment: Thanks it stops that error but when I print out subject in the Homework class it gives me nil would you know why

Comment: Without looking at your code it will be impossible to tell